# Neo4j Cypher iterate collection, extract and upate text

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Heallo
I have a collection property on a relationship (technical information flow) storing the realized logical inforamtion flows:

```
SrcApp1 - EntityA - TrgtApp2, 
SrcApp2 - EntityA - TrgtApp3,
SrcApp3 - EntityB - TrgtApp4
```

I want to update the collection to store only the entities:

```
EntityA,
EntityB
```

Psydo cypher query:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
For each oldDesc in r.DescriptionSet
newDesc = Split(oldDesc," - ")[1] //get the middle value out of SrcApp1 - EntityA - TrgtApp2
r.DescriptionSetNew.Add(newDesc) 
Next oldDesc
```

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Can you show your actual Cypher code and clearly describe your data model? You currently do not seem to be showing any relationships or collections. Also, use neo4j terminology (e.g., by "entity" do you mean "node"?).

Comment: Hi, sorry I added psydo cycpher code in the original post. I basically want to iterate over the collection and extract a specific value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
SET r.fooNew = [d IN r.foo | SPLIT(d, " - ")[1]]
DELETE r.foo;
```